# How to remove the zero labels in Histogram plot in R?

Tags: r, histogram

Any tips to remove the zero labels in between the histogram bars?

[image]

```
hist(links$Survey_Duration, breaks = seq(0,50,5), main = "Survey Duration",
     labels = TRUE, border = "black",
     xlab = "Survey", ylim = c(0, 15), col = "gray", las = 1, xaxt='n')

axis(side=1, at=seq(0,50,5), labels=seq(0,50,5))

abline(v = mean(links$Survey_Duration), col = "royalblue", lwd = 1.5)

abline(v = median(links$Survey_Duration), col = "red", lwd = 1.5)

legend(x = "topright", c("Mean", "Median"), col = c("royalblue","red"),
       lwd = c(1.5,1.5))
```

Comment: If you remove the 0 bars then this would no longer be a histogram. If you want to show categories on the x-axis aggregate your data and use `barplot()`

Comment: i didn't mean to remove the actual values, i just wanted to say that i want to remove the Zero labels from the plot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
# modify data so there's zero in one of the bins
mtcars$mpg <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg >= 25 & mtcars$mpg <= 30, NA, mtcars$mpg)

# save plot parameters
h <- hist(mtcars$mpg, plot = FALSE)

# produce plot
plot(h, ylim = c(0, 14))

# add labels manually, recoding zeros to nothing
text(h$mids, h$counts + 1, ifelse(h$counts == 0, "", h$counts))
```

[image: hist_no_zero]

Comment: You beat me to it. My solution would use `pos = 3` instead of `h$counts + 1`. It seems more natural to use a function argument than a hack. (+1)

Comment: many bins in my plot equal zero, who to project your code on my case?

Comment: It should work just the same, because the `ifelse` statement will recode all the zeros to nothing. If not, can you post maybe a sample of your data?

Comment: HYG;Survey_Duration
46
14
14
12
12
9
15
11
10
9
11
11
14
26
31
10
12
12
10
12

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different answer using the labeling in `hist` instead of adding text afterwards.

You do not provide your data, so I will use some data that is handy to illustrate.

The `labels` argument can specify the individual labels

```
H1 = hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = 3:8, plot=FALSE)
BarLabels = H1$counts
BarLabels[BarLabels == 0] = ""
hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = 3:8, labels = BarLabels)
```

[image: Fixed Labels]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Daniel Anderson, it Ok now (Thumbs Up)

```
links$Survey_Duration <- ifelse(links$Survey_Duration > 15 &
                                links$Survey_Duration <= 25, 
                                NA, 
                                links$Survey_Duration)

h <- hist(links$Survey_Duration, breaks = seq(0,50,5), plot = FALSE)

plot(h, ylim = c(0, 14), main = "Survey Duration", xlab = "Time", col = "gray", las = 1)

text(h$mids, h$counts + 1, ifelse(h$counts == 0, "", h$counts))

axis(side=1, at=seq(0,50,5), labels=seq(0,50,5))

abline(v = mean(links$Survey_Duration), col = "royalblue", lwd = 1.5)

abline(v = median(links$Survey_Duration), col = "red", lwd = 1.5)

legend(x = "topright", 
       c("Mean", "Median"), 
       col = c("royalblue","red"),
       lwd = c(1.5,1.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, in my code I used the `ifelse` part to make a portion of the plot have zeros, so it would match your data The `ifelse` within the `text` function is necessary, the first one shouldn't be (you'll just be recoding all of that data to missing within the 15-25 range).